# Local Name Resolution without Port - MAMP Pro

Tags: macos, redirect, dns, localhost, mamp

This has been bothering me for a while, within MAMP Pro, I've got a few sites setup with "Local Name Resolution", however they only work with a port number.
I've noticed many people are able to get them to work without any port numbers.

E.g Chris Coyier from CSS-Tricks can work directly on **v10.whatup**, where as my own would only work on **v10.whatup**:*8888*

TL:DR.
test.dev:8888 works,
but not test.dev/

Am I missing something/What's the problem?

UPDATE/EDIT:
If I set MAMP Pro port settings to use 80/443 & 3306 (Apache/SSL & MySQL), it seems to work without a port after URL. Although the MAMP Ports setting of: 8888/8890 & 8889 are the default when you first install.

Is the 80/443 setting okay to use, even though it's not default?

Comment: might you have Web Sharing or something similar running on port 80?

Comment: also, how exactly does it fail?

Comment: @Stefan Fisk- No web sharing or anything speicla set up, I'm actually on a brand new Mac, all I've installed really is MAMP pro, sublime etc, nothing specially changed. The error I get from Chrome is: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to test.whatup" (I've got http:// before, but chrome doesn't show it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that changing the ports to 80/443 & 3306 (Apache/SSL & MySQL) instead of the MAMP defaults: 8888/8890 & 8889 will allow use of local name resolution without any port after domain.