# WordPress on localhost{:port number}

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am trying to put my Wordpress site on my localhost{:port} using MAMP.

When I try to access my Wordpress site it redirects from my localhost:8888/site to localhost/site!
I have been trying everything to change it and nothing has worked for me. I have tried this disable plugin -http://marvintam.com/2009/05/wordpress-on-localhost-port-number/ but it still does not work for me.

Any suggestions? Am about to explode with fustration.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a default with Mamp. You just need to change your port numbers, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131093/local-name-resolution-without-port-mamp-pro

Answer (score 0):

a) Check if exists .htaccess on site root directory that redirects for some reason.
b) Check the wp-config file and change WP_SITEURL .
c) Do you really need your web server to run on port 8888 ? if no then go to 
mamp->preferences->ports and change Apache port to 80 and then restart services